# Firebase Crashlytics crash reports are not de-obfuscated after publishing app as a app bundle

Tags: android, android-proguard, crashlytics-android

I recently publish my app to play store as a app bundle and everything is working fine except for above mentioned issue. I have added bellow pro-guard rules in my app and it was working fine with my old builds.

```
#CrashLitics
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

Is there any addition pro-guard rules to include when publishing as a app bundle?

Comment: You need to add class name also in the rules, along with source file and line number table.

Comment: `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,ClassName` like this ?

Comment: I have this problem now, did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted the Firebase team. Their reply was to add `:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease` (or whichever build flavor you are using) to your gradle arguments. It worked for me.

Comment: Can you tell us where to add this?

Comment: Depends on how you build the app, for us we just added the extra gradle task to our build gradle arguments. It looks like `clean ... crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease`

Comment: Please give more details on how and where to add this.

Comment: This task seems to have been renamed, when you run `gradle tasks` you can see, that [Prashant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8475893/prashant17) is now the  correct one

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue. With release build from Android Studio, we were getting de-obfuscated crash logs but with CI it was not working. While observing build logs we realized that `Task :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease` was never called while generating builds from CI. So we updated our build command like this

```
./gradlew clean :app:bundleRelease :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease
```

And then everything worked as expected.